# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. using composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have this composer require :

```
"require": {
    "maximebf/debugbar": "^1.13.1",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "^1.2",
    "symfony/translation": "^4.2",
    "symfony/yaml": "^4.2",
    "symfony/config": "^4.2",
    "symfony/routing": "^4.2",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "^4.2",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.24",
    "leafo/scssphp": "^0.4.0",
    "ins0/google-measurement-php-client": "^2.1.0",
    "ruflin/elastica": "^6.1",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.0",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "^1.0",
    "ezyang/htmlpurifier": "^4.10",
    "xamin/handlebars.php": "^0.10.4",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "^1.11.0",
    "paypal/merchant-sdk-php": "^3.9.1",
    "zircote/swagger-php": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/cache": "^1.5",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "^4.2",
    "friendsofsymfony/http-cache": "^2.5.0",
    "kint-php/kint": "^3.1",
    "trello/trello": "^0.1.1",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.8",
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.6",
    "duccio/apns-php": "^1.0",
    "sentry/sentry": "^2.0.0",
    "symfony/console": "^4.2",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.1",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^7.0",
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
  },
```

And I have the error :

```
Problem 1
    - Conclusion: remove php-http/httplug v2.0.0
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/http-cache ^2.5.0 -> satisfiable by friendsofsymfony/http-cache[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4].
    - sentry/sentry 2.0.0 requires php-http/async-client-implementation ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v2.0.1].
    - sentry/sentry 2.0.0 requires php-http/async-client-implementation ^1.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/guzzle6-adapter[v2.0.1].
    - php-http/guzzle6-adapter v2.0.1 requires php-http/httplug ^2.0 -> satisfiable by php-http/httplug[v2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install php-http/httplug v2.0.0
    - Installation request for sentry/sentry ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sentry/sentry[2.0.0].
```

The thing I don't know why do I get this error, knowing that the line that generates the error is :

```
"friendsofsymfony/http-cache": "^2.5.0",
```

As when I remove it everything works correctly. Any idea why wouldn't composer want to install this package using my current configuration?

**EDIT :**

Previous working state of my require before updating to newer versions :

```
  "require": {
    "maximebf/debugbar": "1.13.1",
    "kriswallsmith/assetic": "1.2.*",
    "symfony/translation": "2.6.11",
    "symfony/yaml": "2.6.11",
    "symfony/config": "2.6",
    "symfony/routing": "2.6",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "2.6",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.17",
    "leafo/scssphp": "0.4.0",
    "ins0/google-measurement-php-client": "2.1.0",
    "ruflin/elastica": "2.3",
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^5.2",
    "mandrill/mandrill": "^1.0",
    "ezyang/htmlpurifier": "4.8.*",
    "xamin/handlebars.php": "^0.10.4",
    "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "1.11.0",
    "paypal/merchant-sdk-php": "3.9.1",
    "zircote/swagger-php": "^1.0",
    "doctrine/cache": "^1.5",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "^2.6",
    "friendsofsymfony/http-cache": "^1.4",
    "kint-php/kint": "^2.1",
    "trello/trello": "^0.1.1",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.8",
    "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8",
    "duccio/apns-php": "^1.0",
    "sentry/sentry": "^1.8",
    "symfony/console": "^2.6",
    "guzzle/guzzle": "~3.9",
    "dompdf/dompdf": "^0.8.1",
    "mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib": "^2.8",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "^6.0",
    "ext-mysqli": "*"
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

If I run your code from clean slate I get a different and more clear problem:

```
  Problem 1
    - Installation request for sentry/sentry ^2.0.0 -> satisfiable by sentry/sentry[2.0.0].
    - sentry/sentry 2.0.0 requires php-http/async-client-implementation ^1.0 -> no matching package found.
  Problem 2
    - friendsofsymfony/http-cache 2.5.4 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - friendsofsymfony/http-cache 2.5.3 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - friendsofsymfony/http-cache 2.5.2 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - friendsofsymfony/http-cache 2.5.1 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - friendsofsymfony/http-cache 2.5.0 requires php-http/client-implementation ^1.0.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Installation request for friendsofsymfony/http-cache ^2.5.0 -> satisfiable
by friendsofsymfony/http-cache[2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.5.4].
```

Your dependencies seem to need something that provides `php-http/` stuff, which are virtual packages, possibly provided by different libs.

You might have had something that provides it and removed it or trying to remove it on this update? Hard to guess.

I would recommend to erase the `composer.lock` and start from scratch.

Comment: Removing the `composer.lock` and starting from scratch would result in the same error though.

Comment: Yes, and the point is that this (missing dependency) is the error you need to correct. Sometimes when you have pending removals needed to satisfy lock file the result ends up unclear and unable to proceed. Dropping lock shows you what underlying problem you _actually_ have.

Comment: Thanks! But this rather than solving the problem, creates another one. Could you possibly add a way to fix the problem that is created by the removal of the `composer.lock`?

Comment: Well, I don't know what your application does or what expectation it has about related functionality, so I can't tell you which packages you need to be using. If you had a previously working state try to figure out if some package was removed that caused this and add it back.

Comment: I edited my OP to include the code that I had before. The code that exists right now is just an updated version of the code I had.